# Image stretching or squeezing ,when I start to change browser size

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a **2000x350 image** and I want to fill that in every display for 350px height. With my code ,what is below, *image starts to stretching or squeezing* ,when I start to change browser or view size. I want to get that image is in center and fill my fixed height.

There is codes

HTML Code:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="image.png" class="image">
</div>
```

CSS
Code:

```
.content{
    display:block;
}

.image{
    width:100%;
    height: 350px;
    background-position:center;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

[**There is fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/s1sfL2au/) ,with my example

Thanks for help!
Sorry for my english ,thats not my native language :)

Comment: try removing `height: 350px;` then resize your browser or try cropping both sides of your image

Comment: @keziah I want to use that fixed height ,I know that works

Comment: Set the fixed height to the parent container, then use width and height auto on the image and give it a max-height and max-width of something bigger than 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CSS3 Flexbox Layout mode:

- remove `width: 100%` from `.image`
- describe .content as:

```css
.content{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/s1sfL2au/3/

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using `background-image` from css:

```
.content{
  display:block;
  background-image: url('http://www.toddsucherman.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/ToddSucherman-2000x350-01.jpg');
  background-position: top, center;
  backgorund-height: 350px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

See the result: https://jsfiddle.net/51ouqj54/

Answer (score 0):

You should the background image, now you are using img tag in html use this code.

Html Code

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

CSS Code

```
.content{background:url(http://www.toddsucherman.com/wp-ontent/uploads/2013/08/ToddSucherman-2000x350-01.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

background-size:cover;
}